# Use of ? when not meaning help

Tags: programming

Trying desperately to understand Michael Trott's Happy Harmonic 2017! post: https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2858495

What does the use of ? in ?t1, ?t2 and ? = (t21 - t12)...mean?
The interpolate and endSegments definitions in the post simply will not run and ? does not fit the format for PatternTest, for instance
Would be very grateful for an insight, many thanks

Comment: Could be a [`PatternTest`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternTest.html), maybe [`MinkowskiQuestionMark`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MinkowskiQuestionMark.html)

Comment: Looks like that post has been deleted.

Comment: @RohitNamjoshi No. Just moved. https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/987658

Comment: Thanks QuantumDot but PatternTest uses_?[test] syntax and never a bare ?, while the Minkowski Function is never shorthanded to a bare ? either.

Comment: Thanks Rohit.  I have been using the url I posted for a week then I asked a question and it moved?

Comment: Hmmm. These `?` don't make any sense. I am afraid the post is corrupted. Maybe due to some font conversion issue?

Comment: Thanks Henrik, ? made no sense to me and why I asked the question.  The ? also appear later in the post but much of the code runs faultlessly as I should expect from an expert such as Michael Trott, so difficult to believe it is a font conversion issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Henrik Schumacher in the comments is correct. If we look at the original post's snapshot  with the Internet Archive's WaybackMachine, dated January 2nd, 2017, we can see that the question marks were originally deltas:

[image]

https://web.archive.org/web/20170102024443/https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/987658

Comment: "Δt1))/δ" so two letters, Δ and δ. Oh and also later τ.

Comment: Hans-Peter - Perfect, thank you so very much. I could not be happier to have spent so much time trying to puzzle this to now actually have it running.   Thanks again to Henrik for having the thought and even more impressed that Hans-Peter was able to access the real archived copy.  I wonder how many other posts have been so affected?  I had tried substituting for the ?'s but had already come to the conclusion not all ?'s were the same!  Thanks again so much for the very kind attention.

Comment: No worries @Linda, that's what the StackExchange is here for. If you are happy that all problems are solved, I would kindly ask you to mark the question as answered by clicking on the checkmark next to the answer.

Comment: More than happy and thanks again Hans-Peter